# unable to get canvas in react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

**I'm trying to access a canvas element inside a react component. The canvas is null error is thrown. Tried to initialize canvas with useEffect(), it didn't help. Tell me, please, am I doing something wrong?
UPD: instead of createRef() I tried to use useRef(), it also doesn't work :(**

My React Component

```
import {createRef, useRef} from "react";

export default function InteractiveElement() {
    let r = useSelector(state => state.r);
    const imageSizePx = 400;

    const ref = createRef();
    const canvas = ref.current;
    const chart = canvas.getContext('2d');


    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        if (e.clientX < imageSizePx / 2 && e.clientY < imageSizePx / 2) {
            const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = e.clientX - rect.left; // x position within the element.
            const y = e.clientY - rect.top; // y position within the element.

            console.log("X = ", getXTopLeft(x));
            console.log("Y = ", getYTopLeft(y));
        }
    });

    const getXTopLeft = (px) => {
        return -3 * (1 - px / (imageSizePx / 2));
    }

    const getYTopLeft = (px) => {
        return 3.3 * (1 - px / (imageSizePx / 2));
    }

    return (
        <div className="main__coord">
            <canvas className={"interactive_element"} ref={ref} id={"chart"}/>
            <img src={require("../style/coordinate-form.jpg")} alt={"coordinate-place"}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `useRef` hook should be used here instead of `createRef`.
- The ref is not initialized during the first render (as React needs to see the returned JSX first); use it in an effect instead.

```js
const ref = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = ref.current;
    const chart = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      if (e.clientX < imageSizePx / 2 && e.clientY < imageSizePx / 2) {
          const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
          const x = e.clientX - rect.left; // x position within the element.
          const y = e.clientY - rect.top; // y position within the element.

          console.log("X = ", getXTopLeft(x));
          console.log("Y = ", getYTopLeft(y));
      }
    });
}, []);
```